# Remove dots from Gmail sender field

Tags: gmail, mailing-list

I am trying to unsubscribe from a mailing list but cannot. Here's the deal:

- I subscribed using `firtlast@gmail.com`
- Tried to unsubscribe by sending an unsubscribe email to list
- Didn't work because I initially signed up for gmail using `first.last@gmail.com`

I have the From field set up as `firstlast@gmail.com`, but the mailing list sees that Gmail provides the sender field as `first.last@gmail.com`. Unsubscribing requires email verification!

Is there a way to get Gmail to use an alternate sender field or am I stuck?

Comment: do you have two Gmail accounts? "firstlast" and "first.last"

Comment: @William: Gmail ignores dots in Gmail addresses. `first.last@gmail.com` is equivalent to `firstlast@gmail.com` is equivalent to `fir.stla.st@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer is that it is not possible.  I'll need to contact the mailing list admin directly.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple to do by creating an alias account.

1. Go to `Settings | Accounts and Import`
2. In the `Send mail as:` section, click on "Add another email address you own"
3. Enter your email address without any dots (e.g., `firstlast@gmail.com`)
4. Now, send your unsubscribe message using the new address you added. (You'll simply change the `From:` field of the compose window)

Comment: I have done this, but it only changes the From: field, not the Sender: field; the mailing list only pays attention to the sender field.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer. You're going to either 1) research the mailing list software to find an alternative unsubscribe method, 2) contact the administrators of the mailing list and ask them to remove you manually, or 3) use a different mail client (Thunderbird? Mail2Web?) so that you can control the sender field.

Answer (score -1):

As some mailing lists provide an online interface to unsubscribe check if the mailing list you've subscribed to has one. Otherwise, if you don't think you'll receive any useful emails from the email address of the mailing list, set a filter in Gmail to delete the message as soon as it arrives. Alternatively, you can report the unwanted messages as spam & Gmail may start stop sending such mails to your Inbox.